# Why this SQL trigger isn't saving any data?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

So I have this trigger:

```
delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER check_liters 
 AFTER INSERT ON reports_data_sheet_area_brut
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF (NEW.fuel > 10) THEN
    UPDATE fuel_check
    SET fuel_value = NEW.fuel
    Where id = NEW.vehicule_id;
 ELSEIF (NEW.fuel > 20) THEN
    UPDATE fuel_check
    SET fuel_value2 = NEW.fuel 
    Where id = NEW.vehicule_id;
 END IF;
END$$
```

It can be added properly on triggers but it doesnt add data in fuel_check table when fuel>10 or 20.

This is reports_data_sheet_area_brut :

http://i.prntscr.com/a1f7af8c28c447e98eb0cf111e544596.png

This is fuel_check table(for the trigger):

http://i.prntscr.com/75f1467563d14febbdfd8b749a11013d.png

When I will try to add a value:

```
INSERT INTO reports_data_sheet_area_brut (vehicule_Id,area_Id,area,status_Id,status,start_time,end_time,duration,start_fuel_level_liters,end_fuel_level_liters,fuel,distance,consum_h )
                       VALUES
(43,432,"ceva",2,"Motor Oprit","2016-06-29 09:07:04","2016-06-30 10:07:06",30937,674,674,15,0,0);
```

After this SQL it only add column in reports_data_sheet_area_brut but not in fuel_check table from trigger.

Comment: You are using `update` command which will update an existing row if the where condition is fulfilled, else does not do anything.

Comment: I saw that, but INSERT or INSERT INTO doesnt work either.

Comment: I think the logic should be more appropriate as `IF (NEW.fuel > 10 and NEW.fuel  <=20) then ...... ELSEIF (NEW.fuel > 20) then .... `

Comment: I do have the fuel column in the reports_data_sheet_area_brut table.

Comment: Yea I get that logic, but what can I use instead of UPDATE ?

Comment: Can't really see the s3 files you need to set public read ACL, better create a fiddle on http://www.sqlfiddle.com and with some sample data, I will try the trigger.

Comment: Update only works if there is an existing row with the matching condition. You have a condition as `Where id = NEW.vehicule_id;` so first check if there is a row in that that table with the supplied vehicule_id if not the update will never work. Or if your business logic is to add a new entry then use `Insert into ....`

Comment: And check the fuel_check table to make sure you insert all the required fields and that there is no trigger on that table which undoes what you did in your trigger.

Comment: This is the fiddle link, It doesnt let me add the trigger: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849c3

Comment: If I try to chance UPDATE with INSERT TO I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where id = NEW.vehicule_id; ELSEIF (NEW.fuel > 20) THEN INSERT INTO fuel_' at line 7

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7efbc8/1).